# In the Simpsons credits why does it say “starring” and then after a few names it says, “also starring?”

Tags: the-simpsons

In the Simpsons credits why does it say “starring” and then after a few names it says, “also starring?” My guess is that the “also starring” aren’t regular voices but the characters voices are on almost every single show.

My guess is that it means they are contract rather than whatever the other voice actors are

Comment: Not an expert but I think this is related to the billing language negotiated in the actors’ contracts. Many other shows do the same thing.

Comment: @BCdotWEB no someone else linked to it but now the link is gone. i added a link back to here in case they have an answer

Comment: @paulie_d had left a link but for some reason it’s gone

Comment: It doesn’t have an answer. not duplicate